# MediatR Publish() command stuck in combination with await *.ToListASYNC()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mediatr

I have a strange problem where calling Publish() gets stuck (command never finishes) if it is used in combination with ToListASYNC(). It works with ToList(). I prepared a minimum example. Sadly due to db dependency not a click and run but I think you can get it going quite quick.

```cs
namespace ShowcasePublishGetsStuck
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Database;
    using Database.Enums;
    using Database.Models;
    using MediatorEvents.Notifications;
    using MediatR;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class ShowcaseToListAsyncStuck
    {
        private MyDbContext _db;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public ShowcaseToListAsyncStuck(
            MyDbContext db,
            IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;

            DemoGettingStuck(CancellationToken.None).Wait(); //I run it in ctor with Wait. Not sure if important
        }

        public async Task<bool> DemoGettingStuck(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _mediator.Publish(new KycCompanyCreatedEvent(0), cancellationToken);
            
            _mediator.Publish(new KycCompanyCreatedEvent(0), cancellationToken).Wait(cancellationToken);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                await FunctionThatCallsSimplePublish(cancellationToken); //WORKS!
            }

            var purchasesSync = _db.Purchases
                .Where(x => x.Id == 405)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var _ in purchasesSync)
            {
                await FunctionThatCallsSimplePublish(cancellationToken); //WORKS! YES EVEN THIS WORKS!
            }
            
            var purchasesAsync = await _db.Purchases
                .Where(x => x.Id == 405)
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken); //HERE! It is identical just ToListAsync. Should be the same but isn't.

            foreach (var _ in purchasesAsync)
            {
                await FunctionThatCallsSimplePublish(cancellationToken); //FAIL: STUCK!?!?!?!?!?!?!?
                //NEVER REACHES HERE
            }

            return true; //NEVER REACHES HERE
        }
        
        public async Task FunctionThatCallsSimplePublish(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await _mediator.Publish(new KycCompanyCreatedEvent(0), cancellationToken);
            await Task.Delay(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I use .NET 6 and ToListAsync() is available via import Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

I use this nuget package of EntityFrameworkCore and generally this version number:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
```

For me it doesn't make any sense why ToList() + foreach works but ToListAsync() + foreach doesn't.

MediatR I use v11.0.0 but I also tried v12.1.1. and same result.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="11.0.0" />
```

For completeness here also my handler:

```cs
[UsedImplicitly]
public class KycCompanyCreatedEventHandler : INotificationHandler<KycCompanyCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IMyProvider _myProvider;
    private readonly MyDbContext _db;

    public KycCompanyCreatedEventHandler(IMyProvider myProvider, MyDbContext db)
    {
        _myProvider = myProvider;
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task Handle(KycCompanyCreatedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask; // Breakpoint here not reached on .ToListAsync() foreach
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? A bug where?

PS: this is a crosspost of my [github issue](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/957)

Comment: Don't try to run async code in a constructor, that is never going to end well

Comment: Blocking on async code (i.e., `Wait`) [can cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) I describe on my blog.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yesterday I tried again by creating a separate admin-only endpoint that triggers my hangfire function and like to use await and this works like it should. If someone creates an answer about this I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments of my question as well as answered on my github issue the root cause is the `.Wait()` in the constructor. I ended up creating a separate api call that calls my function. Async await is no problem there and that api call is useful in any case.

Mediatr package is great and this is just something you should be aware of...